# App Not available in some countries

Tags: google-play, country, mobile-country-code

I just released one app yesterday. It's showing up in my country.

But I found out that it's not showing in some countries. How I can check that it's available in all the countries or not. What I need to do if I want to make int available in all the countries >

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your app, maybe [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140?hl=en&ref_topic=3452890) helps. Otherwiese, have you read the [localiaztion guidlines](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html) (like it is suggested by google to do so before releasing an app)? As far  as I remember you are asked in the developer console in which country you want to rlease you app, but maybe this was only for payed apps.

Comment: No, it asks for both paid and free apps. But problem seems to be something else. Thanks I will try to look into.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this question is related to this one: [This item isn't available in your country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665582/this-item-isnt-available-in-your-country)

[quoting durbnpoisn answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37665617/4911442):

> Check your listing in the Developer control panel.
>
> There is a listing for where the app is available (Pricing &
>   Distribution section - Manage Countries). The checkbox for whatever
>   country needs to be checked on. Otherwise, it's locked out.
>
> For convenience, there is a box at the top that says "SELECT ALL
>   COUNTRIES".
>
> For what it's worth, if the country in question is not on the list,
>   there is nothing you can do about that. There are a number of rules
>   and regulations about where Google Play can distribute stuff. You have
>   no control over that.