# This item isn't available in your country

Tags: android, google-play

I had uploaded a new application on google play store, and everything done, but some users have a problem in downloading the application:
"This item isn't available in your country", I don't know what to do in this case, can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming issue.

Comment: This is a programming issue - there might be config missing. The SDK being used may have a bug in it... etc

Case in point I am going through this exact issue myself while integrating with RevenuCat SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Check your listing in the Developer control panel.

There is a listing for where the app is available (Pricing & Distribution section - Manage Countries).  The checkbox for whatever country needs to be checked on.  Otherwise, it's locked out.

For convenience, there is a box at the top that says "SELECT ALL COUNTRIES".

For what it's worth, if the country in question is not on the list, there is nothing you can do about that.  There are a number of rules and regulations about where Google Play can distribute stuff.  You have no control over that.

Comment: Where can I find this list ?

Comment: Pricing & Distribution section.  I've updated the answer accordingly,.

Answer (score 0):

I moved to a new country and i was facing this issue whenever i tried to install some apps that are famous in this country so i had tried various ways to resolve this issue through online forums unfortunately nothing worked so i contacted the google play services support desk and they helped me in resolving this issue, the steps I followed are below:

1. Go to https://payments.google.com/payments
2. Click on settings at left side of screen
3. Create a new payments profile in which you will be giving the country to which you have moved recently.
4. After successfully completion of creating a payments profile, go to phone settings => all apps => Google play store => clear cache and data.
5. Click back and open system apps => search for download manager => clear cache and data.
6. Most probably it should work right now if not wait for an hour.